# Receiving emails and storing it in jTable

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, netbeans-7

I am trying to receive mails from my email account. But i am not able to store it in `jtable`. I want to do this because when one row is selected the contents will be displayed in `jTextArea`. This is my code snippet.

```
public void connect() {
    final String pass = set.pass;
    final String user = set.uname;
    try {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.gmail.com");

        props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory", 995);

        props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        props.put("mail.imap.port", 995);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);

                }
            });


        Store store = session.getStore("imap");

        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "mymail@gmail.com", "mypaswword");

        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");

        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        Message[] msg = folder.getMessages();

        FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();
        profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
        folder.fetch(msg, profile);
        jTable2.add(msg);


        folder.close(true);
        store.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I am getting error in this line

```
jTable2.add(msg);
```

How am I supposed to do it..

Comment: Independent of the problem you're asking about, you might want to fix theses [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

[`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) is used to add components to a container rather than data to the `JTable`. You could create a custom `AbstractTableModel` specifically for storing `Message` references

```
public class MessageTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Message> messages;

    public MessageTableModel(List<Message> messages) {

        this.messages = new ArrayList<Message>(messages);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        Object value = "??";
        Message message = messages.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                for (Address a: message.getFrom()) {
                    builder.append(a);
                    builder.append(",");
                }
                value = builder.toString();
                break;

            case 1:
                value = message.getSubject();
                break;
        }

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
    }

    /* Override this if you want the values to be editable...
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //....
    }
    */

    /**
     * This will return the Message at the specified row...
     * @param row
     * @return 
     */
    public Message getMessageAt(int row) {
        return messages.get(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using netbeans.so it has already defined that for me.the problem is that the add(msg) is not accepting Message[] msg array

Comment: 2 problems: 1 `add` is undefined for `JTable` as already stated 2) you need to decide what particular information you want to display in the table, e.g just sender and subject

Comment: @user3433164 Yes there are technically `add()` methods available because `JTable` inherits from [java.awt.Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html). However, aside from the fact that you quite correctly say that it doesn't accept the object type you're trying to pass, it wouldn't accomplish what you're trying to do anyway. Reimeus's answer steers you to the correct path which is to manipulate the table's model. See the official [Swing JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)