# adding emails to jtable

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, netbeans-7

I am trying to receive mails from my email account. But i am not able to store it in jtable. I want to do this because when one row is selected the contents will be displayed in jTextArea. This is my code snippet.

```
public void connect() {
    final String pass = set.pass;
    final String user = set.uname;
    try {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.gmail.com");

        props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory", 995);

        props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        props.put("mail.imap.port", 995);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);

                }
            });


        Store store = session.getStore("imap");

        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "mymail@gmail.com", "mypaswword");

        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");

        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        Message[] msg = folder.getMessages();

        FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();
        profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
        folder.fetch(msg, profile);
        ArrayList messagelist=new ArrayList();
for(int i=msg.length-1;i>0;i--)
{
    messagelist.add(msg[i]);
}
jTable2.add(messageList);

        folder.close(true);
        store.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I want to add three values to jtable from emails which are "Serial no" , "Subject" and "Date" and each row should be clickable such that the email contents are displayed in JTextArea. I am using Netbeans to write this code.

Error in line

```
jTable2.add(messageList);
```

Plz Help!!!!!

Comment: What is the error? Don't be shy to add the stack trace (you should always).

Comment: The error is only in that line when i type the line...I have not run the code as the error in this line...but i don't understand the error

Comment: If you don't paste the stack trace no one can help you. The code you provided is incomplete (e.g. jTable2 is not defined) and does not compile. Please read the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide and post something we can work with. Also, if jTable2 is a JTable, you don't call `add` to add content to it, you call `setModel`. You can read the JTable tutorial in the Java Tutorials.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receiving emails and storing it in jTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591836/receiving-emails-and-storing-it-in-jtable)